# Cannot Click Specific TagName (<Li>) with VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue to click specific tag, I cannot click the element, I want to click "February" but My script didnt work , here the script that I've made :

```
Set kkptS = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("li")
For Each kkpt In kkptS
  If HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("li")(44).innerText = "february" Then
       HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("li")(44).getAttribute("class") = "active"
  End If
Next kkpt
```

and The HTML Code :

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">          
    <li class="" "="">      
        <a href="#m0" data-toggle="tab">    
            Year</a>
    </li>       
    <li class="active">     
        <a href="#m1" data-toggle="tab">    
            January</a>
    </li>       
    <li>        
        <a href="#m2" data-toggle="tab">    
            February</a>
        
        </ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code assumes that the class names `"nav nav-pills nav-stacked"` occur only once in the HTML document or that the desired ul tag is at least the first with these class names.

**If you only need to click `febuary` you can hardcode the click with:**
`HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("nav nav-pills nav-stacked")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(2).Click`

**If you need to click any month use this sub:**

```
Sub ClickMonthTab(HTMLdoc As Object, month As String)

Dim kkptS As Object
Dim kkpt As Object

  Set kkptS = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("nav nav-pills nav-stacked")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
  
  For Each kkpt In kkptS
    If InStr(1, kkpt.innertext, month) Then
      kkpt.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
      Exit For
    End If
  Next kkpt
End Sub
```

**You can use the sub in this way:**

```
Sub CallClickMonthTab()

Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Dim monthName As String

  'Your code to open document
  '...
  '...
  
  'Set month and click the right tab
  monthName = "febuary"
  Call ClickMonthTab(HTMLdoc, monthName)
  
  'More of your code
  '...
  '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much, it works, You are amazing

Comment: @Mr.New Please mark my answer as solution.

Comment: Oke, Than you so much